# Install new development tools on old system

Tags: linux, centos, gcc, gdb

I run 32 bit Centos 6.9 Linux with installed development tools for it with command:

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

But it installs very old GCC and GDB. What is the best way to install newer tools supported by my system?

Comment: Try to create a Virtual Machine or a container (virtualbox, qemu, docker, vagrant etc...)

Comment: Build e.g. gcc-5.4.0 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bJY1P6C16zveBwWyu0h771ufee-aGIjo/view?usp=sharing ,,, and use `$ export CC=gcc53 CXX=g++53 (&& ./configure)` when building a later GDB.

Comment: I decided to make project on old Centos since I will need need to run this application on current machine. I was expecting that compiled code in original machine will use most native libraries from Centos 6.9

Answer (score 0):

You should never replace the packages in the base repositories, however, you can get newer compilers and development tools out of Software Collections.  They install alongside the OS packages.

See:  https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/

Comment: Does it men I can use old GCC/GDB and newer one from Software Collections?

Comment: They install side by side. You’d have to invoke the scl command to see the new versions.